# Is it actually possible to make an amputated hand move with electricity?

Tags: electricity, voltage, biology

I was watching a TV show that involved the police tracking down an insane person who was using deceased limbs to perform experiments on. It then cuts to a scene where they find the safehouse with what appears to be a moving hand connected to electrical wires on a table in a closed fist knocking on the table.

Then ¨Fact VS Fiction¨ kicked into my mind and made me wonder, is it actually possible to make deceased limbs move as long as the cells in it are semi active just like the brain sends electricity to the limbs to make them move?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics

Comment: May I ask how it is not related to physics?

Comment: It is more biology than physics. I am not sure if there is a biology SE

Comment: I don’t know whether this question would be on-topic at [biology.se] or not; I’d advise to search for duplicates first.

Answer (score 1):

While the connections between the neurons work through the exchange of chemicals, to make the transmission fast the neurons use the electrical pulses running along the axons (long fibers growing from the cell). So, oversimplifying, the neural system is a connection of wires transmitting electric pulses. If you apply electric pulse to neurons it may transmit to the muscle and act as a command to contract/relax.

This is known since the experiments by Galvani with amputated frog legs
[image]